# How to query Class having same value

Tags: c#, class, data-binding, listbox

Please consider that I'm not good at English.

List of Class 'Student' is bind to ListBox and Displaymemeber is 'group' field.

My goal is showing the group without overlapping. (Just A and B)

But here my code display like this.

[ListBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pmFD.jpg)

How can i display just A and B?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Student st1 = new Student("Kim", 15, Group.A);
        Student st2 = new Student("Lee", 15, Group.A);
        Student st3 = new Student("Park", 15, Group.B);

        Student.Add(st1);          
        Student.Add(st2);          
        Student.Add(st3);

        listBox1.DataSource = Student.LstStudent;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "group";
    }
}


public enum Group
{
    None,
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public class Student
{
    private static List<Student> _LstStudent = new List<Student>();
    public static List<Student> LstStudent
    {
        get
        {
            return _LstStudent;
        }
    }

    public Group group { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }


    public Student(string name, int age, Group group)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.group = group;
    }

    public static void Add(Student student)
    {
        LstStudent.Add(student);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to only display the groups you can use LINQ to filter your `List<Student>`.

Try changing

```
listBox1.DataSource = Student.LstStudent;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "group";
```

To

```
listBox1.DataSource = Student.LstStudent.Select(x => x.group).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: @YeongSeokOh I have updated my answer to include the `.ToArray()` method chain.  I was not sure if the `DataSource` property required an array or simply an `IEnumerable`. Please accept the answer if it now answers your question, Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask one more? How can get all the student that group is A?